# Time sum, convert to liters per hour excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using a spreedsheet to run our fuel strategy in an endurance car event.

I have two buttons that add the time to two cells, say pit in cell `A1`, pit out cell `B1`. The button click event for both cells is `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Time()` , addressed for each cell, and the cell text will be `6:33:23 AM`, for example.

In the 3rd cell, `A3`, I use the following `=TEXT(A2 - A1, "hh:mm:ss")` which gives me, for example, `00:42:17`.

Here is part 1 of my 2 part problem.

I want to sum column `A`. I get the wrong answer. I get it will be simple, but I am just missing it unfortunately.

Part 2 is I then want to use the amount of fuel added at the pit stop with the `A3` time to get an average fuel consumption per hour, again, getting wildly wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to capture the time as a number not as test so you can subtract the times then convert back to a time.

```
Sub Test()

  Dim e As Double
  Dim s As Double
  
  s = (TimeValue(Time)) 'Get Current Time as a number
  Debug.Print s
  e = s + (30 / (86400)) 'Add 30 seconds for testing you'd repeat the formula for s
  Debug.Print Format(e - s, "hh:mm:ss")  'Print out as time.
  

End Sub
```

Sample Output:

```
 0.840752314814815 
00:00:30
```

You should be able to adjust this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will give it a bash and see how I go. I fully thought it would be simple, just couldn't see it, Thanks